# $\pm$ sign in $y=\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If: 
$$y=\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
Then: 
$$\sin(y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
$$\cos^2(y)=1-\sin^2(y)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$ \tan^2(y)=\sec^2(y)-1=1+x^2-1=x^2$$
Therefore I would say:
$$\tan(y)=\pm x$$
However, my calculus book says (without the $\pm$):
$$\tan(y)=x$$

Question: Why can we remove the $\pm$?

Comment: I think we can write as $tan(y)=|x|$

Comment: Essentially because $a=\arcsin(b)$ and $\sin(a)=b$ aren't equivalent statements. The $\arcsin$ function is usually defined in such a way that $\cos(\arcsin(b))\ge0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get rid of the $\pm$ sign because in $y=\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, $x$ and $y$ have to have the same sign: For $-\pi/2 < y\le\pi/2$ if $x$ is positive, then $y$ is positive then also $\tan(y)$ is positive. If $x$ is negative then $y$ is negative then $\tan(y)$ is negative.

Therefore, if $ \tan^2(y)=x^2$ then $ \tan(y)=x$

Answer (score 1):

The sign of $\tan(\theta)$ is not uniquely determined from an equation $\sin(\theta) = a$, which has two solutions with opposite signs for the tangent.   Under any convention for choosing one of the two $\theta$'s as the value of $\arcsin(a)$, the tangent is uniquely determined. The convention consistent with what you wrote is $\arcsin \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

Comment: In other words, this "error" is due to a somewhat arbitrary convention, and not a mistake in performing the algebra.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but let's we were to have the convention to chose the value for tangent on $(\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$. If we plug in $\tan y = -x$, we would still get $y = \arcsin (\sin (-y)$. Would this reduce then to $y=y$?

Comment: It reduces to y=y when y is in the range of arcsin.

Comment: A similar question is what is arcsin(sin(y)) under the usual convention, for y in (pi/2, 3 pi/2).  @Ovi